# What are some standard patterns for formatting numerical values with a wide range of values like cryptocurrency prices?

Tags: user-expectation, tables, data-tables, formatting, currency

I am trying to build a screen where I need to display cryptocurrency prices. The problem with these prices are that some of them such as BTC have 2 digits after the decimal, some of them have 4 while a vast majority of them have 8 digits.

What are some standard patterns used to format numerical values in a table that contains a wide range of values?

**My Current Screen**
[image]

**Other Providers**

**Coinmarketcap**
[image]

**Coingecko**
[image]

**Coincodex**
[image]

**Coincap**
[image]

Coinlib
[image]

Coinpapricka
[image]

Comment: Even though this question is very similar in nature to the question @locationunknown pointed out, it is becoming more relevant as more cryptocurrency and blockchain applications are being developed so I think it is still worth exploring further.

Comment: thank you @MichaelLai my question here was very specific to whether i should be showing things the way I am on my current screen

Comment: @MichaelLai True, these applications are becoming more common, but the question is the same as was asked previously. The two questions were asked by the same person, for (presumably) the same application, about the exact same thing: How should you display dollar amounts with varying degrees of decimal precision.

Comment: I think your solution is similar to how I would approach it. I was going to suggest using adding padded numbers as a suffix. But I see that you already this that; however I would make the padded numbers a little more visible (less opacity / change color).

Try squinting with your eyes to see what I mean; it looks like the numbers are all over the place right now.